# What is the intrinsic curvature of a sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry

How would an ant living on the surface of a sphere know the curvature without understanding 3d? 
Normally the curvature contains an extrinsic variable namely the sphere radius. 
The ant doesn't know any extra dimensions or "non real"  objects like coordinates, charts or basis vectors. 
Knowing only the curvature and circumference how would he calculate the surface?

Comment: If he knows circumference, then he knows the radius.

Comment: The radius extends in the third dimension which he does not see.

Comment: 'The radius extends in the third dimension', well, even if it does, it shouldn't matter. Even if he doesn't see it.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it is not intrinsic to the sphere, the ant only knows the 2 dim tangent spaces and the radius is orthogonal to them.

Comment: If the ant adds up the angles in a triangle, the difference between the total and $\pi$ will give an indication of the curvature.

Comment: See, for example, slides 9/10 in [this link](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/thomas.leistner/talks/ugsem20100908.pdf).

Comment: Wow theorems elegantissimum, that's Sam truly nice piece of math , actually helps answer the question

Comment: But only partially. The link shows a variation of gauss bonet theorem I guess , for this to work I need to know the surface of a for example major geodesic triangle which is one quarter the sphere area but how can the area be calculated only from inside the sphere?

Comment: this qn doesnt make sense because an ant doesnt know math